# Get variables from webpage with Chrome Extension - localstorage?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am building a Chrome extension to be used with a mapping page. The user logs into the map, and a lot of variables are passed from a database into the map.

When the extension is opened is there a way to pass these variables into it? I was thinking about LocalStorage:

As a test I tried this in the map page HTML

```
if (typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
localStorage.setItem("firstname", "hello");
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "world");
}
```

And then in the extension content I just tried

```
alert('My name is ' + localStorage.getItem("firstname") + ' ' +
localStorage.getItem("lastname"));
```

I can see the variables under localstorage in the map page developer tools. But I see a different set in the extension.

It seems as if the extension can't read these. Is there a way I can send these over, or do I need a different method?

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using to retrieve the variables?

Comment: I just tried a different way of writing to storage (see edited code)and it still returned "My name is null null". The problem seems to be that if I look at localstorage on the console, the page is  "Local Storage>http://www..." and contains the variables. The extension shows as "Local Storage>Chrome Extension:ghjghgjh...." and shows a different set of variables. So I suppose what I am asking is can I write to the local storage for the extension from the webpage?

Comment: The localStorage that you're using != http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html. There seems to be some pretty big differences.

Comment: @PaulAston I don't know if the change you made was anything to do with my answer, but I deleted it because I found the two methods are completely interchangeable, which I did not know.  However, I *would* recommend using `setItem()` and `getItem()` so that you don't accidentally override any properties or methods.  I know this was nothing to do with your issue, but I think it's worth noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is message passing in chrome. See this article https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

The basics would be something like this

```
chrome.extension.getLocal({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "status"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

.

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getLocal"){
      sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
    }else{
      sendResponse({}); }
});
```

You could also look into using chrome storage rather than local storage 
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: Yes this is the only way. For security you cant access storage or variables of the injected webpage only its dom. Besides message passing you can also store it in the dom which might be easier.